# How can I correctly implement this Hibernate NamedQuery that obtain a list of objects?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am absolutrly new in Hibernate and I have the following situation that I don't know how to handle.

So I have these 2 entities classes:

1. **KMCountryArea** that map the **KM_COUNTRY_AREA** table on my databse:

   ```
   @NamedQueries({
       @NamedQuery(name = "kmCountryByName", query = "SELECT country FROM KMCountryArea country WHERE country.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by country.idCountryArea")
   })

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "KM_COUNTRY_AREA")
   public class KMCountryArea implements Serializable {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       private Long idCountryArea;

       @Column(name = "nomeFolder")
       private String nomeFolder;

       @OneToOne
       private KMCountry country;

       // GETTER & SETTER METHODS
   }
   ```
2. **KMCountry** that map the **KM_COUNTRY** table on my databse:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "KM_COUNTRY")
   public class KMCountry implements Serializable {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       private Long idCountry;

       @Column(name = "country")
       private String name;

       @Column(name = "workingHours")
       private String workingHours;

       // GETTER & SETTER METHODS
   }
   ```

So, as you can see, into the **KMCountryArea** class I have the **KMCountry country** field that is associated to an instance of the **KMCountry** entity class.

To do it I used the **@OneToOne** annotation

```
@OneToOne
private KMCountry country;
```

From what I understand, into my **KM_COUNTRY_AREA** table on my DB I will have a field that will contain the KMCountry id (**idCountry**). Is it right or am I missing something?

If it is correct now my problem is that I need to create a named query that give a value of the **nomeFolder** field of the **KMCountryArea** will retrive the list of all the related **KMCountry** object.

I am trying to do something like this (I can't try it at this stage of works and I am absolutly not sure that this is the right way to do it):

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "kmCountryByName", query = "SELECT country FROM KMCountryArea country WHERE country.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by country.idCountryArea")
})
```

Is it all my reasoning correct (how to bound togheter the 2 tables and the named query) or am I missing something?

Please, can you help me to accomplish this task?

Tnx

Comment: There is no field "idCountryArea" in "country". It is called "idCountry"

Comment: @NeilStockton ok I think that you are right. I have correct it following your remark. Now do you think that the reasoning and implementation og my query are correct?

Comment: You have used an alias in your query "country" yet that is also the name of a field in the candidate entity - change it to avoid conflict

Comment: @NeilStockton now I will try, if it is not a problem, can you please show me a snapshot so I can understan well how it works and avoid errors?

Comment: A snapshot? You have "SELECT country FROM KMCountryArea country WHERE country.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by country.idCountryArea" and you cannot have "country" as your ALIAS for KMCountryArea ... since that class has a field called "country". Just use an alias of "c" for example ... SELECT c FROM KMCountryArea c WHERE c.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by c.idCountryArea

Comment: @NeilStockton If you put this as answer I will accept it, tnx so much :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
"SELECT country FROM KMCountryArea country WHERE country.nomeFolder = :nomeFolder order by country.idCountryArea"
```

and you cannot have "`country`" as your ALIAS for KMCountryArea ... since that class has a field called "`country`". Just use an alias of "c" for example ...

`SELECT c FROM KMCountryArea c WHERE c.nomeFolder = :nomeFolder order by c.idCountryArea`